# xmldoc.documentElement.childNodes.length object required

Tags: xml

sorry, but I've looked arround and find nothing to solve ti... the xml file load well but when I run:

```
    xmldoc.documentElement.childNodes.length
```

throws an 'object required' message and just crash...

Comment: What programming language is this? Javascript? Java? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your xmldoc object is initialized.